# What comes after thrice?

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs, triple-thrice, recurring-events

When you want to say something occurred only one time, it's "once". Two is twice, three is thrice. What's for four?

Answer (score 4):

[Four times.  Then five times, then six times, and so forth.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/what-comes-after-once-twice-thrice)

Comment: Haha, someone voted to delete this above all sensible answer.  What's up with that?